# Extracting and exporting registry values on remote computer

Tags: powershell

I try to find out which computers are still set to connect to the Internet via proxy servers.
I therefore try to read the values ProxyServer and Proxy Enabled values in AD.
After searching around on the Internet, I came up with this:

```
$computername = Get-Content -path ".\pclist2.txt"

if (test-connection -computername $computername -quiet)
{
foreach ($pc in $computername)
    {
    $loggedon =@(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $pc -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_ComputerSystem)[0].UserName; 

    #IEKeys
    $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $pc.computer)
    $regkey = $reg.OpenSubkey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings")
    $LMPS = $regkey.GetValue("ProxyServer")
    $LMPE = $regkey.GetValue("ProxyEnable")
    $reg2 = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('CurrentUser', $pc.computer)
    $regkey2 = $reg2.OpenSubkey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings")
    $CUPS = $regkey2.GetValue("ProxyServer")
    $CUPE = $regkey2.GetValue("ProxyEnable")
    Add-Content ".\IEproxies.csv" "$pc;$LMPS;$LMPE;$CUPS;$CUPE"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, only the variable for ProxyEnable of CurentUser is exported to the file.
Other values are blank, and I receive no error message running the script.
Could anyone help me on this one?

Thx in advance,

Thierry

Comment: FYI you don't need to double the back-slash in the paths: in PSH backslash is not the character escape character backtick is. (I would add those characters but the comment subset of markdown really doesn't want to allow me to display either character :-(.)

Comment: Suggestion: run under the ISE debugger and examine the values you get back in code, not just what is written; Ie. fix getting the values, then sort out saving them.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I think the problem lies in the lines containing GetValue :
$CUPS = $regkey2.GetValue("ProxyServer")
$CUPE = $regkey2.GetValue("ProxyEnable")
The value of ProxyEnable is displayed in my export (0 in this case), but the value ProxyServer is not, although when I check the registry, both are containing a value.
Maybe is it because the ProxyEnable a REG_DWORD and the ProxyServer is a REG_SZ, but in this case I don’t know how to retrieve this last one. (PS: I also tried without the double \\ in the path, without success).